# Seems like Ubuntu 23.04 installation does'nt work for me?

Tags: system-installation

recently I've tried to install Ubuntu alongside of my win10 but I do exactly what I supposed to do in each step of installation and at the end of installation where it's supposed to copying files and everything , it does not work and just seems like freezing and does nothing.
also from the commence of installation Ubuntu keep alerting an message about detecting a problem and ask me if i want to sent a report all the time.
pls help me out of this situation .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi)

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of the Ubuntu installer freezing partway through is defective sectors on the hard disk. Swapping the hard disk with another hard disk will fix this problem. If you want to rerun the Ubuntu installer from the beginning simply remove the Ubuntu live USB, turn of the computer, and restart the computer with the Ubuntu live USB inserted in a USB port.